# Exposing Member Variables with ButterKnife

Tags: android, annotations, butterknife

Curious question, I'm using ButterKnife and I just discovered you can't use in private methods because ButterKnife creates classes that use them. **Doesn't that violates the principle of encapsulation?** I mean, then your variables will be exposed to other classes as well, no?

Comment: Same thing with Dagger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally right, using `Butterknife` violates the principle of encapsulation.

---

`Butterknife` uses its own generated code to perform view look-ups. And those look-ups are done in separate class(-es) hence the fields cannot be private.

**Quote:**

> The generated code exists in a class outside of this class, thus the
>   fields are truly being accessed outside of the class, hence not
>   private. If you see other generated code that is accessing private
>   fields, it is using reflection to by-pass the private access
>   restriction, which means you have fields that look private but are
>   actually being accessed outside of the class.

Using reflection would not only be the same thing *under the hood* but also significantly slower compared to view look-ups.

---

Anyway, those classes that use Butterknife to perform view binding should not be initialized anywhere apart of classes that are responsible for the same thing (view binding, that is) so violating encapsulation is not a big deal. For example: `Activities` can have instances of `Fragments`, `Fragments/Activities` can have instances of `RecyclerViewAdapters` because all of these are responsible for view binding, but `ViewModel` *(MVVM architecture)* for example  should not have an instance of `Fragment/Activity` or any `View` in general because it has nothing to do with view binding.

---

Good luck. :)